# How to adjust the size of an image inside a QGraphicsView scene

Tags: image, qt, size, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I want to display an image in a QGraphicsView with a QGraphicsScene. My code is very basic :

```cpp
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
scene->addPixmap(QPixmap(qApp->applicationDirPath() +"/france.gif"));
ui->myGraphicsView->setScene(scene);
ui->myGraphicsView->fitInView(scene->sceneRect());
```

My problem is that my picture has a wrong size. It is very small, with wrong proportions, and in the center of `myGraphicsView`.

With `qDebug`, I know that my picture is loaded successfully, and it has a size of about 100x800px. `my GraphicsView` is smaller, so I want to resize my picture to adjust it with `myGraphicsView` size.

The graphics view is set in the `mainwindow` form, and the scene is declared in the header: `QGraphicsScene scene;`.

I tried many things, but the graphics view is always blank, or contains the small version of the picture.

I also tried this example: [Qt GUI Development - Displaying a 2D grid using QGraphicsView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279567/qt-gui-development-displaying-a-2d-grid-using-qgraphicsview), but same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sceneRect()` may not be what you think it is unless you specifically set it. Also you are missing `aspectRatioMode` in `fitInview` call which can distort it image, sometimes resulting in "small" appearance.

```
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
QGraphicsPixmapItem p = scene->addPixmap(QPixmap(qApp->applicationDirPath() +"/france.gif"));
ui->myGraphicsView->setScene(scene);
ui->myGraphicsView->fitInView(p, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

Comment: I think the OP was thinking about itemsBoundingRect() to get the rect around all (the only) items in the scene: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsscene.html#itemsBoundingRect

Comment: I try your solution Stephen  : 
`QPixmap pixmap(qApp->applicationDirPath() +"/france.gif");
    QGraphicsPixmapItem* item = scene.addPixmap(pixmap);
    ui->myGraphicsView->setScene(&scene);
    ui->myGraphicsView->fitInView(item, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);`
And now i get this result :
http://images.meteociel.fr/im/6981/result_hnx1.PNG

Comment: Okay another thing... I try this last code in the MainWindow . It works great. I try tgis code in a QWidget which is displayed after clicking a button on MainWindow and it doesn't work : i have the same result : http://images.meteociel.fr/im/6981/result_hnx1.PNG